# Button onload calls function

Tags: javascript, html, function, button, onload

I have the following button

```
<button type="button"
  title="Previous value:"
  ***onload="test()"***
  class="btn btn-warning mb-2" style="padding: 4px 8px 4px 8px; border-radius: 1rem;">
 <i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle text-white"></i>
</button>
```

Which I want it when it loads to call the test() function

```
function test() {
    console.log("I am in");
}
```

in reality this function will be creating a popover. But it doesnt seem to be calling the function.
(No, onclick or hover is not helping me.)

Any suggestions, ideas how to achieve that?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey Chris, whith the onload event on a button, do you really want to create your popover  immediately when the button is rendered on the page or when the user does a specific action with this element ?

Comment: Hi @Philippe, I really want to display the popover when the page is loaded. So immediately, because I use it as notification icon next to all the altered values of my page.

Comment: Okay, so why do you focus on this button ? ;) You'd better listen the `window` `onload` event.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/588048/4698373

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onload` event is only supported on these HTML tags:

```
<body> <iframe> <img> <input type="image"> <link> <script> <style>
```

take a look at: [HTML onload attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_onload.asp)

Comment: You're welcome ^^ consider accepting an answer by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Comment: i will wait to see if somebody will offer a workaround first. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

```
    <button type="button" title="Previous value:" onclick="test()" class="btn btn-warning mb-2" style="padding: 4px 8px 4px 8px; border-radius: 1rem;">
 <i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle text-white"></i>
</button>

<script>

function test(){
    //alert("test");
    console.log("I am in");
}
</script>`enter code here`
```

Comment: I have exactly the same, but it doesnt work. Thank you anyway for the answer

Comment: @ChrisTsag do you have JS enabled? & which browser are you using

Comment: yes, I do have it enabled and I am using Chrome. The function works if I call it with onClick. but not onload

Answer (score 0):

Try using Ajax and call the function by id or class by button click.

Comment: button click cannot work in my case. Can you please provide more information about the ajax call?  Thank you

Comment: Search for ajax use on Google and make changes in your source file